# Menu Font Garbled in Java Application

Tags: java, fonts, menu

I am trying to change the menu font in a Java application (OmegaT http://www.omegat.org).  However, when I change the default menu font in Windows 7 64-bit (under "Advanced Appearance Settings...") the menus as well as file dialogs become garbled as this screen-shot shows:
http://www.sbbic.org/omegat/1.jpg (even selecting Tahoma as the default font causes this problem).

Has anyone ever seen this garbling text before and know how to solve it, or have some suggestions on troubleshooting?

Is it a Java issue?  OmegaT is supposedly just using the default fonts from Windows...

I have contacted the developers of OmegaT, but they are at a loss for what the issue is.  I thought by posting my question here, others might have encountered the same error and know how to resolve it.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I assume that you are a user of this program, not a creator or contributer, and that you don't have direct knowledge of how the program was constructed, such as the library used, the version of the library, the set up etc.  If so and this problem is affecting your use of the product, your best bet is to contact the developers or distributers of the program.

Comment: Yes, I have contacted the developers of the program (they are not sure what the issue is either) - I posted here because I thought perhaps it is a Java related issue, and not the program itself, so others might have encountered it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted FNTCACHE.DAT in my system32 directory and rebooted, and it seemed to fix it.  Weird.
http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/49179-windows-7-64-bit-fonts-not-shown-4.html
so I guess it was a Windows issue and not Java at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off Windows ClearType font settings worked me for.  This took me hours to figure out.  The app I was using that was causing me problems was ReportWorks for PowerSchool.

Comment: This worked for me (our customer actually, I've never been able to duplicate the problem on any of my machines) too.  No idea what caused the breakage, but turning off ClearType makes the problem go away!  If not solving the root cause, at least it makes the application usable again!

Answer (score 0):

Do not Turn off ClearType, just tune it. By Andrey Rast ([Source](http://www.rarst.net/software/cleartype-install4j-java-bug/)) search ClearType and tune it. After that Java error will disappear.

I already tried it for Arduino IDE and JetBrains IDE. It gave me the same error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 33 incompatible with Text-specific LCD contrast key

And, check your Java versions for Env si JRE to be the same.