# JFrame and JOptionPane are not clear

Tags: java

Whenever I execute `JFrame` of `JOptionPane` this is how its displayed.   I have the latest version of eclipse and JDK. I use Windows 8. What might be the issue?!

[image]

```
public static void main(String args[]){

String disp="2.40894673";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, disp);

}
```

the problem occurs in all the codes. This is a sample code I wrote th problem occurs in this too.

Comment: Some code would be useful to give you a hint.

Comment: Agreed, please add the code you are using to display this box.

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue. But that's as far as I can get with the given information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update your graphics and card drives.
2. If you're using Mac then as I found in [this
   page](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-editorEclipse/topics/java-graphics-card-driver-compatibility-issue.html)
   look at:

   ```
   Preferences > Fonts > Text antialiasing
   ```
3. If you're using Windows then [from this
   answer](https://superuser.com/a/341653) be sure it's checked:

   ```
   Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Display → Adjust ClearType text
   ```
4. Then check your font settings for windows, menu items and dialog
   boxes:

   ```
   Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Personalization → Window Color → Advanced appearance settings
   ```

Most of times just step 1 solves the issue.

Try them and if worked let me know.

**UPDATE**

- Try turning off ClearType from Control Panel as indicated in step 3,
  as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15097628/2180785)
- Also try deleting `FNTCACHE.DAT` from `System32` as mentioned in
  [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4720806/2180785).
- Also as said in [this
  forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1239595?start=0&tstart=0)
  try to change your screen resolution, and also reducing Hardware acceleration.

Let me know if any of them solved the issue.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 tried all three doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user3734503 what's your encoding? And what happens if you move mouse over the Label?

Comment: hey Thanks a lot!!! I deleted the FNTCACHE.DAT and turned off the ClearType ! IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

I've written a code for the same, and it works fine.

**Program:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SDialog
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    String disp="2.40894673";

    // create a jframe
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // show a joptionpane dialog using showMessageDialog
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,disp);
    System.exit(0);
   }
 }
```

Comment: i tried this code!! still the same problem occurs!! The problem might nt be in the code! i tried installing the JDK again! doesnt seem to work